# Twig templates are not loading

Tags: 8, theming

I am using Drupal 8 from [github:drupal/drupal@a9ac0fbf17](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/tree/a9ac0fbf17), but having problems creating custom template, using Twig template engine.

Here is template file structure:

.
├── README.txt
├── screenshot.png
├── templates
│   └── html.html.twig
└── custom.info.yml

**html.html.twig** file is not being loaded. I have tried to change ownership/permission of the files, but it didn't help. I turned on `twig_debug` and getting:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: _theme('html') -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--front.html.twig
   * html--node.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/modules/system/templates/html.html.twig' -->
```

which, I assume means it is loading default template from `core/modules/system/templates/`.

Here is the content of my **html.html.twig**:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * basic html structure of a single Drupal page.
 */
 #}

 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head {{ html_attributes }}>
   <title>{{ head_title }}</title>
   {{ page.head }}
   {{ page.styles }}
   {{ page.scripts }}
</head>
<body {{ attributes }}>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page.content }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    {{ page.scripts('footer') }}
</body>
</html>
```

What might I be missing? let me know if you need more info.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Are you using the template in a theme or a module?

Comment: I'm using it in a theme. I got it working just now. I copied bartik theme and made my modifications on it, but the structure and contents of files remaining the same. I am still not sure why it didn't work, probably cache issue. I would answer my own question, if I knew the reason, but if I find out, I'll post answer here.

Comment: Do you try clear cache (`drush cache-rebuild` or admin/config/development/performance).

Comment: I too am getting like this : <!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * html--front.html.twig
   * html--.html.twig
   x html.html.twig
--> , I have added twig files in my_module/templates folder. I have cleared cache, but my twig file is not getting loaded. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

To disable cache for development(tiwg + Drupal cache) :

first copy and rename the sites/example.settings.local.php to be sites/default/settings.local.php

then open settings.php file in sites/default and uncomment these lines:

```
# if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/settings.local.php')) {
#   include __DIR__ . '/settings.local.php';
# }
```

Now open settings.local.php and change the below lines to "TRUE".

```
$config['system.performance']['css']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
$config['system.performance']['js']['preprocess'] = FALSE;
```

and uncomment all these to Disable the render cache and Disable Dynamic Page Cache

```
# $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
# $settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

for twig cache open "development.services.yml" and update the below parameters.

```
  twig.config:
    debug : true
    auto_reload: true
    cache: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If your template does not load usually is because is been cache. Its recommend to disable the caching twig in Drupal 8 with developing.

The easier way to "**Disable Drupal 8 caching during development**" is using DrupalConsole.

```
drupal site:mode dev
```

Source - [Debugging compiled Twig templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1903374)

After you disable your cache you can use the `cache:rebuild` Drupal Console command to clear the cache.

```
drupal cache:rebuild
```